# find recursive specific file

Tags: php, recursion

I'm trying to find all the files that called "testunit.php".
In addition i want to cut the first 23 chars of the string.

I tried this but this is not working.I get all the files.

```
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($parent);
$display = Array ( 'testunit.php');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file=>$cur) {
{
if ( In_Array ( $cur, $display ) == true )
               $file = substr($cur, 23)
               fwrite($fh,"<file>$file</file>");

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Look e.g. here. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#92233 you are fetching the information wrongly in the loop, it needs to be `as $file => $cursor` (`cursor` being an iterator object)

Comment: It's not working..i tried to do `foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file=>$cur) {`

Answer (score 1):

see if [glob](http://php.net/glob) helps you

Comment: Why? The `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` is new, fancy, OOP, and can search recursively. If he fixes his existing code, he'll have a solution superior to `glob()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class TestUnitIterator extends FilterIterator
{
    public function accept()
    {
        return (FALSE !== strpos(
            $this->getInnerIterator()->current(),
            'testunit.php'
        ));
    }
    public function current()
    {
        return sprintf(
            '<file>%s</file>',
            substr($this->getInnerIterator()->current(), 23)
        );
    }
}
```

**Usage ([codepad (abridged example)](http://codepad.org/kZomysgZ)):**

```
$iterator = new TestUnitIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
            '/path/to/iterate/over',
            FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME
        )
    )
);
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    echo $file, PHP_EOL;
}
```

*Disclaimer: I wasn't in the mood to mock the filesystem or setup the required test files, so the above might need a little tweaking to work with the filesystem. I only tested with an ArrayIterator but there shouldn't be much to do if the above produces errors.*